# EMNIST dataset training high loss

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been trying to train a model with the EMNIST dataset (as I also need letters) using tensorflow.

Here's where I'm getting the data: https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/emnist

My code for the model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

train_ds, test_ds = tfds.load('emnist', split=['train', 'test'], shuffle_files=True)

x_train = train_ds.map(lambda i: i['image'])
y_train = train_ds.map(lambda l: l['label'])
x_test = test_ds.map(lambda x: x['image'])
y_test = test_ds.map(lambda y: y['label'])

def train():

    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(62, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(tf.data.Dataset.zip((x_train, y_train)).batch(32), epochs=8)
```

But the training output is:

```
Epoch 1/8
21811/21811 [==============================] - 126s 6ms/step - loss: 3.8161 - accuracy: 0.0527 
Epoch 2/8
21811/21811 [==============================] - 130s 6ms/step - loss: 3.6866 - accuracy: 0.0539
Epoch 3/8
21811/21811 [==============================] - 117s 5ms/step - loss: 3.6854 - accuracy: 0.0544
Epoch 4/8
21811/21811 [==============================] - 127s 6ms/step - loss: 3.6851 - accuracy: 0.0545
Epoch 5/8
21811/21811 [==============================] - 125s 6ms/step - loss: 3.6850 - accuracy: 0.0546
Epoch 6/8
21811/21811 [==============================] - 126s 6ms/step - loss: 3.6849 - accuracy: 0.0546
Epoch 7/8
21811/21811 [==============================] - 133s 6ms/step - loss: 3.6849 - accuracy: 0.0547
Epoch 8/8
 9537/21811 [============>.................] - ETA: 1:07 - loss: 3.6862 - accuracy: 0.0543
```

Given this incredibly high loss, I can't really think that I'm doing this correctly. I'm wondering if there's something I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can load the full dataset as a single `Tensor` or `NumPy array` by using `batch_size=-1` to batch all examples in a single `tf.Tensor`. Then use `tfds.as_numpy` for the conversion from `tf.Tensor` to `np.array` as below.

```
(img_train, label_train), (img_test, label_test) = tfds.as_numpy(tfds.load(
    'emnist',
    split=['train', 'test'],
    batch_size=-1,
    as_supervised=True,
))
```

Then use the `Conv2D` layer for better model training because you are using an image dataset.

```
def train():
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), input_shape=(28, 28, 1), activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(62, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(img_train, label_train, epochs=8)
```

Output:(You can see the result below. The model loss decreased and accuracy increased comparatively)

```
Epoch 1/20
21811/21811 [==============================] - 72s 3ms/step - loss: 0.5864 - accuracy: 0.8078
Epoch 2/20
21811/21811 [==============================] - 71s 3ms/step - loss: 0.4661 - accuracy: 0.8376
Epoch 3/20
21811/21811 [==============================] - 71s 3ms/step - loss: 0.4411 - accuracy: 0.8441
Epoch 4/20
21811/21811 [==============================] - 71s 3ms/step - loss: 0.4252 - accuracy: 0.8483
Epoch 5/20
21811/21811 [==============================] - 71s 3ms/step - loss: 0.4145 - accuracy: 0.8515
Epoch 6/20
21811/21811 [==============================] - 71s 3ms/step - loss: 0.4064 - accuracy: 0.8536
Epoch 7/20
21811/21811 [==============================] - 71s 3ms/step - loss: 0.3998 - accuracy: 0.8555
Epoch 8/20
21811/21811 [==============================] - 71s 3ms/step - loss: 0.3939 - accuracy: 0.8570
Epoch 9/20
21811/21811 [==============================] - 71s 3ms/step - loss: 0.3894 - accuracy: 0.8582
Epoch 10/20
21811/21811 [==============================] - 71s 3ms/step - loss: 0.3857 - accuracy: 0.8591
```

For more details, please refer to the `TensorFlow Datasets's` [performance tips](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/performances).